# Greatest common divisor identity proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. I want to prove: $$gcd(a,b) = gcd(a,b+ma)$$

First part: Let $c \in \mathbb{N}$ be the gcd of $a$ and $b$.

It's not hard to prove that $c$ is a divisor of $b+ma$.

Now I want to show, that we can't find a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $k > c$, where $k$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b+ma$. Then $c$ is also the gcd of $a$ and $b+ma$.

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

$c$ is the gcd of $a$ and $b$ which means the following:

$$\forall \lambda,\lambda' \in \mathbb{R}: \left(k > c \wedge k \cdot \lambda' = a \wedge k \cdot \lambda = b \implies \lambda \notin \mathbb{Z} \vee \lambda' \notin \mathbb{Z} \right)$$

Let be $k > c $ and $ k \cdot \lambda' = a $ and $ k \cdot \lambda = b + ma$.
We assume $\lambda, \lambda' \in \mathbb{Z}$

It holds: $$k \cdot \lambda = b + ma = b + m \cdot \left(k \cdot \lambda' \right) \Longleftrightarrow b = k \cdot \underbrace{\left(\lambda - m \cdot \lambda' \right)}_{\in \mathbb{Z}}$$

That's not possible since $c$ is the gcd of $a$ and $b$. That means our assumption is wrong, which means $\lambda \notin \mathbb{Z} \vee \lambda' \notin \mathbb{Z}$

All in all $c$ is the gcd of $a$ and $b+ma$.

Second part would be to show that the gcd of $a$ and $b+ma$ is the gcd of $a$ and $b$.

I do not really like my proof, is there a smarter way to show this?

Cheers

Comment: What do you do when m isn't the gcd(a,b)?

Comment: m is an arbitrary integer.  It absolutely does not need to be the gcd(a,b)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. I am showing, that $m = gcd(a,b) \implies m = gdc(a,b+ma)$ and $m = gdc(a,b+ma) \implies m = gcd(a,b)$, hence $m = gcd(a,b) \Longleftrightarrow  m = gcd(a,b+ma)$, hence $gcd(a,b) = gcd(a,b+ma)$

Comment: Let a = 6 k = 8 and m= 539. Prove gcd(6,8) = gcd(6, 8+539*6).  m is *not* the gcd(6,8).  You can *not* assume m is gcd(a,b).

Comment: sorry fleablood, i had messed up some variables. fixed it.

Comment: It is easier IMHO to prove that the sets of common divisors of $(a,b)$ and $(a, b+ma)$ are equivalent - i.e., that any number which divides $a$ and $b$ also divides $b+ma$, and that any number which divides $a$ and $b+ma$ also divides $b$.  Once you show that they're equivalent as sets, then clearly their greatest members are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g=(a,b)$. Then $g|a$ and $g|b$ and for any $d$ such that $d|a$ and $d|b$, $d\le g$.

Now note that $g|a$ and $g|b+ma$. Suppose that $d|a$ and $d|b+ma$ where $d>g$.

But this implies that $d|(b+ma)-m(a)$, or $d|a$. Thus we have found a number which divides $a$ and $b$ greater than $g$, a contradiction. Thus $g=(a,b+ma)$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$. Then, $d\mid a+mb$.

Suppose $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b+am$. Then, $d\mid (-m)a+b+am = b$.

All this follows from $d\mid x$ and $d\mid y \implies d\mid nx+my$.

To recap, any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is that of $a$ and $b+am$; and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much, Myath

Comment: You're welcome.